# Fortran strange behavior when timing subroutines

Tags: performance, fortran, behavior, intel-fortran

The strangest behavior happens when I'm timing the code shown below. It's long but it's just doing matrix multiplication with different ways of passing arguments. For `matmul0` I use explicit shape, for `matmul1` I use assumed shape, and for `matmul2` I use assumed shape plus I use pointers inside the subroutine to point to the matrices (don't ask me why I do this, it doesn't matter). The thing is, when I time the three subroutines, I get something like:

```
Time explicit shape: 3.712099
Time assumed shape: 12.55620
Time assumed shape + pointer: 3.821299
```

Now, if I comment the third subroutine (the one with pointers), this time I get something like:

```
Time explicit shape: 3.712099
Time assumed shape: 3.824401
Time assumed shape + pointer: 0.00000
```

Why is this happening? And why doesn't it happen to the first subroutine too? I'm running on Intel Core i3, Intel compiler, no optimization flags, just `ifort test.f90 -fpp` (the `fpp` is for preprocessing the timer macro). Full code below.

```
#define timer(func, store) call system_clock(start_t, rate); call func; call system_clock(end_t); store  = store + real(end_t - start_t)/real(rate);
program test
    interface
        subroutine matmul1(A, B, C)
            real :: A(:,:), B(:,:), C(:,:)
        end subroutine
        subroutine matmul2(A, B, C)
            real, target :: A(:,:), B(:,:), C(:,:)
        end subroutine
    end interface
    real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: A, B, C
    integer, parameter :: m = 500, n = 500, o = 500
    integer, parameter :: loops = 100
    integer :: start_t, end_t, rate
    real :: time
    allocate(A(m,n), B(n,o), C(m,o))
    A(:,:) = 1; B(:,:) = 2; C(:,:) = 0

    time = 0
    do i = 1, loops
    timer(matmul0(A, B, C, m, n, o), time)
    end do
    print*, 'Time explicit shape:', time

    time = 0
    do i = 1, loops
    timer(matmul1(A, B, C), time)
    end do
    print*, 'Time assumed shape:', time

    time = 0
    do i = 1, loops
    ! timer(matmul2(A, B, C), time)
    end do
    print*, 'Time assumed shape + pointer:', time

end program

subroutine matmul0(A, B, C, m, n, o)
    integer :: m, n, o
    real :: A(m,n), B(n,o), C(m,o)
    do i = 1, m
        do j = 1, o
            do k = 1, n
                C(i,j) = C(i,j) + A(i,k)*B(k,j)
            end do
        end do
    end do
end subroutine

subroutine matmul1(A, B, C)
    real :: A(:,:), B(:,:), C(:,:)
    do i = 1, size(C,1)
        do j = 1, size(C,2)
            do k = 1, size(A,2)
                C(i,j) = C(i,j) + A(i,k)*B(k,j)
            end do
        end do
    end do
end subroutine

subroutine matmul2(A, B, C)
    real, target :: A(:,:), B(:,:), C(:,:)
    real, pointer :: A0(:,:), B0(:,:), C0(:,:)
    A0 => A; B0 => B; C0 => C
    do i = 1, size(C,1)
        do j = 1, size(C,2)
            do k = 1, size(A,2)
                C0(i,j) = C0(i,j) + A0(i,k)*B0(k,j)
            end do
        end do
    end do
end subroutine
```

Comment: Fortran is [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order)! You should better re-order your loops...

Comment: I know that, I'm just doing a quick comparison of performances with different ways to pass arguments. I'm actually also comparing use of derived types for matrices.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with `ifort` and the `size()` function calls inside the loops...

On my machine, your code yields:

```
 Time explicit shape:   3.145800
 Time assumed shape:   14.98891
 Time assumed shape + pointer:   14.82460
```

I rewrote the subroutines to re-use the array shapes:

```
subroutine matmul1(A, B, C)
    real,intent(in) :: A(:,:), B(:,:)
    real,intent(out) :: C(:,:)
    integer :: m, n, o

    m = size(C,1)
    n = size(C,2)
    o = size(A,2)
    do i = 1, m
        do j = 1, n
            do k = 1, o
                C(i,j) = C(i,j) + A(i,k)*B(k,j)
            end do
        end do
    end do
end subroutine
```

[`matmul2` was adjusted similarly...]

Now, I get:

```
 Time explicit shape:   3.159100
 Time assumed shape:   3.009802
 Time assumed shape + pointer:   3.567401
```

Interestingly, `gfortran` seems not to have this problem.

Commenting out the third subroutine call has no effect on either compilers on my machine, so I can't help you there :(

Comment: I tried what you did and I'm still getting the same results. Worse is that it happens in two different machines, though with the same compiler (ifort 14.0.2).

Comment: Mhm, I only have `ifort 13.0.1` available on one machine. I tried it with `gfortran` (up to 4.9.1) on different machines, but no change. Can you try `gfortran`?

Comment: Juts tried `gfortran` and the strange behavior doesn't appear. It's definitely an issue of Intel compiler. I think I'm going to have to post this to Intel forum.